# Multiply Columns from Separate Tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables `RepairDetails` and `Repairs`.

Inside the `Repairs` table, is a list of the types of repairs we offer and their cost.

```
+-------------+---------------+
| repair_desc | repair_price  |
+-------------+---------------+
|  BasicHB    |   50.00       |
|  AdvHB      |   80.00       |
|  CCRepair   |   40.00       |
|  CCReplace  |   80.00       |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Inside the `RepairDetails` table, is a record of `unit_id` and each `unit_id` has a `detail_id` attached to it that lists the number of each type of repair applied to the unit.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------+----------+-----------+
| detail_id |  unit_id  |  BasicHB | AdvHB | CCRepair | CCReplace |  
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------+----------+-----------+
|  1        |     1     |     2    |  0    |   0      |   1       |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

The `unit_id` is used as a primary key on another table that ties it to an `order_id` and then `order_id` is primary key on yet another table that ties it to a `customer_id`.

What I need is to create a query that will take the value within the columns on the `RepairDetails` table and multiply them by their respective `repair_cost` column in the `Repairs` table. In the end, I'd like to be able to make this query based on the `customer_id`. This is where I get a bit more lost because I'm sure there will be more than one `JOIN` of some kind to get from the `customer_id` to the `order_id` to the `unit_id` to the `detail_id`. Any help on that end would be appreciated as well!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does it have to be a stored procedure? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```
select  detail_id
      , unit_id
      , BasicHB*(select repair_price from Repairs where repair_desc = 'BasicHB') 
          as BasicHB_RepairDetailCost
      , AdvHB*(select repair_price from Repairs where repair_desc = 'AdvHB') 
          as AdvHB_RepairDetailCost
      , CCRepair*(select repair_price from Repairs where repair_desc = 'CCRepair') 
          as CCRepair_RepairDetailCost
      , CCReplace*(select repair_price from Repairs where repair_desc = 'CCReplace') 
          as CCReplace_RepairDetailCost
from RepairDetails
--inner join Units on (Units.unit_id = RepairDetails.unit_id)
--inner join Orders on (Orders.order_id = Units.order_id)
--inner join Customers on (Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id)
--where Customers.customer_id =
```

On this basic scale it should work for both Oracle and SQL Server.

If it's not what you're looking for, please state so in the comments and I'll try to adjust it for you.

Comment: Works great! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is a pain.  Why are some in columns and others in rows?  I would pivot the tables so they have the same structure:

```
select rd.*,
       (rd.BasicHB * r.BasicHB) as BasicHB_price,
       (rd.AdvHB * r.AdvHB) as AdvHB_price,
       (rd.CCRepair * r.CCRepair) as CCRepair_price,
       (rd.CCReplace * r.CCReplace) as CCReplace_price,
from repairdetails rd cross join
     (select max(case when repair_desc = 'BasicHB' then repair_price end) as BasicHB,
             max(case when repair_desc = 'AdvHB' then repair_price end) as AdvHB,
             max(case when repair_desc = 'CCRepair' then repair_price end) as CCRepair,
             max(case when repair_desc = 'CCReplace' then repair_price end) as CCReplace             
      from repairs r
     ) r;
```